# Fetch yahoo mail content within date range using YQL

Tags: email, oauth, yql, yahoo-mail

I am using yahoo query language with web service to retrieve yahoo mails using oauth. Now my use case is to download all emails with in given time range.

How can i construct the query to fetch data in time range?

Query i used(it is not working) :

```
select message from ymail.msgcontent where (mids) in (SELECT  mid  FROM ymail.messages WHERE fid="Sent" and messageInfo.receivedDate >  1393417547
```

Can someone help me write a right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of directly selecting mid, select messageInfo.mid will fix it

Below query did the magic : 
select message from ymail.msgcontent  where (mids) in (select messageInfo.mid  from ymail.messages where messageInfo.receivedDate > 1392658116)